Lambda with CDK won't start - JSONDecodeError and BrokenPipeError
I'm trying to deploy an image-based, Python Lambda that includes the AWS CDK library.  When I try to run the function in AWS, it fails to start up.
I'm using this Dockerfile:
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.12
COPY * ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/

RUN dnf update -y
RUN dnf install -y git
RUN curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash -
RUN dnf install -y nodejs
RUN npm install -g aws-cdk

RUN --mount=type=secret,id=gitconfig,target=/root/.gitconfig pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD [ "main.lambda_handler" ]

This spins up and runs just fine for me on my local machine with Docker.  It deploys to AWS fine, but when the function gets invoked, I'm seeing these messages in the log:
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 10005.00 ms  Phase: init Status: timeout

[ERROR] JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1331, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 935, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 995, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    import aws_cdk as cdk
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aws_cdk/__init__.py", line 1519, in <module>
    from ._jsii import *
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/aws_cdk/_jsii/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    __jsii_assembly__ = jsii.JSIIAssembly.load(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jsii/_runtime.py", line 55, in load
    _kernel.load(assembly.name, assembly.version, os.fspath(assembly_path))
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    self.provider.load(LoadRequest(name=name, version=version, tarball=tarball))
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 354, in load
    return self._process.send(request, LoadResponse)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 332, in send
    self._next_message(), _ProcessResponse
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 251, in _next_message
    return json.loads(self._process.stdout.readline(), object_hook=ohook)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/json/__init__.py", line 359, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Exception ignored in atexit callback: <bound method _NodeProcess.stop of <jsii._kernel.providers.process._NodeProcess object at 0x7f7608954da0>>

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/site-packages/jsii/_kernel/providers/process.py", line 295, in stop

self._process.stdin.close()

BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 111268.11 ms Phase: invoke   Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.Unknown

START RequestId: 6930a835-0ac0-55be-aa00-f72e6fd53c01 Version: $LATEST

Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown

END RequestId: 6930a835-0ac0-55be-aa00-f72e6fd53c01

It seems like maybe the NodeJS runtime is not starting up as expected, but I can't figure out any way to troubleshoot this further right now.

What is your lambda doing during initialization (outside of the handler)? How long does it take on your machine? What is the memory limit for the function?

Nothing special during initialization.  I'm initializing a few boto3 Clients, but the code doesn't even get to that point as it is failing on import aws_cdk as cdk.  On my local machine it takes about 14s to initialize.  The memory limit is just set to the default 128MB, so I may try upping that to see if it helps.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Thanks to @gshpychka's questioning I was able to figure out that the memory limit was too low.  I went from the default 128MB to 1024MB, and the function works now.  Looking at the reports, it seems like it needs more than 800MB to run.

Try increasing the Lambda timeout as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-timeout.html

The timeout applies to the execution time after the init phase. Since the timeout occurs in the init phase (which has a non-adjustable limit of 10 seconds), this answer does not apply.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
